# Spring MVC 3 controller request handler common

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a controller that handles few requests that have to be checked for existence of the same cookie value. This means that in each request handler I have to perform the same check.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/Path")
    public String Handler1(@CookieValue(required = false, value = "Cookie") String cookie) {

        if (cookie != null) {
            handleNoCookie();
        }
        handleRequest1();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/AnotherPath")
    public String Handler2(@CookieValue(required = false, value = "Cookie") String cookie) {

        if (cookie != null) {
            handleNoCookie();
        }
        handleRequest2();
    }
and so on...
}
```

Is there a way to extract the duplicated check this into some method that will do the check before the actual handler executes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [interceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) to ... "intercept" requests and process your logic if the cookie isn't there. You can make it fire before the controller is hit via the **preHandle** method.

API: [HandlerInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html)

Comment: Thanks! That looks like a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If there are a large number of Handler methods, you could look into Spring's AOP to implement the cookie check advice for all the methods.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html

Comment: Thanks btreat. But I was hoping to stay in the MVC framework.

Answer (score 0):

AOP interceptor suggested in other answers is an configurational overkill.

Similar functionality can be achieved using [@ModelAttribute](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html) annotation. It is available since Spring 2.5. Methods annotated using `@ModelAttribute` must generate parameters for the view model. These methods are called before every method annotated using `@RequestMapping`.

It seems to be working if the annotated method returns nothing (void-method). In this case it works as some imaginary "BeforeEveryRequest" annotation. It looks like this:

```
@ModelAttribute
public void tagController(HttpServletRequest request) {
    request.setAttribute(VERSION_PARAMETER, version());
}
```

UPDATE:
There is a small side effect. It adds a dummi value to the model. Key is a string "void" and the value is `null`.